# Azure CLI - Not able to download packages using az artifacts universal download

Tags: azure, azure-devops, angular-cli

After downloading the source code from Azure Devops, we run below command to download all the packages.

```
az artifacts universal download --organization "https://dev.azure.com/TestLtd/" --feed "3ce80a2fe791" --name "release" --version "7.60.47" --path .
```

The above command was working fine few days back and now started throwing below error.

Error message:

```
**The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\knack/cli.py", line 233, in invoke
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 663, in execute
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 726, in _run_jobs_serially
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 718, in _run_job
  File "C:\Users\Test\.azure\cliextensions\azure-devops\azext_devops\dev\common\exception_handler.py", line 31, in azure_devops_exception_handler
    reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\six.py", line 719, in reraise
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 697, in _run_job
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 333, in __call__
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/command_operation.py", line 121, in handler
  File "C:\Users\Test\.azure\cliextensions\azure-devops\azext_devops\dev\artifacts\universal.py", line 98, in download_package
    return artifact_tool.download_universal(organization, project, feed, name, version, path, file_filter)
  File "C:\Users\Test\.azure\cliextensions\azure-devops\azext_devops\dev\common\artifacttool.py", line 42, in download_universal
    return self.run_artifacttool(organization, args, "Downloading")
  File "C:\Users\Test\.azure\cliextensions\azure-devops\azext_devops\dev\common\artifacttool.py", line 67, in run_artifacttool
    proc = self._tool_invoker.run(command_args, new_env, initial_progress_message, _process_stderr)
  File "C:\Users\Test\.azure\cliextensions\azure-devops\azext_devops\dev\common\external_tool.py", line 74, in run
    self.start(command_args, env)
  File "C:\Users\Test\.azure\cliextensions\azure-devops\azext_devops\dev\common\external_tool.py", line 33, in start
    self._proc = subprocess.Popen(
  File "subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1440, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
To check existing issues, please visit: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues
To open a new issue, please run `az feedback`**
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually had the same error just now (and the same error a year ago).

The error message indicates that the Python script could not find the binaries of ArtifactTool. Quickly check if you can locate the binaries with `ls ~/.azure/azuredevops/cli/tools/artifacttool/*/artifacttool`.

If there are binaries there, try to check the folder `ls ~/.azure/azuredevops/cli/tools/artifacttool/`. Chances are, you'll have multiple folders:

- an empty `ArtifactTool_win10-x64_0.2.287/` (or very similar folder, with different version string) which is almost empty
- and another folder that contains all binaries needed (with very cryptic name)

If that's the case, the artifactTool is basically corrupted, but `az update` cannot fix it because it just checks for the folder existance and does not actually check for the correctness of the content.

Just delete the `ArtifactTool_win-x64_0.2.287/` folder and try to execute `az universal download` again. It should automatically fix that folder & its issues.